# libgdx ScrollPane - Doesn't scroll?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scrollpane

I'm making a lobby in a multi-player game, which may have any number of players displayed in a table.  I have the following code:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2, 0);
    camera.update();

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    stage.setCamera(camera);
    stage.setViewport(WIDTH,HEIGHT,false);

    ScrollPaneStyle paneStyle = new ScrollPaneStyle();
    paneStyle.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(WizardsDuel.atlas.findRegion("cavebg"));
    paneStyle.vScrollKnob = new TextureRegionDrawable(WizardsDuel.atlas.findRegion("GUI/slidernob"));
    paneStyle.hScroll = paneStyle.hScrollKnob = paneStyle.vScroll = paneStyle.vScrollKnob;

    Table container = new Table();
    table = new Table();
    ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(table,paneStyle);
    container.add(pane).width(WIDTH).height(HEIGHT);
    container.row();
    container.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    stage.addActor(container);

    font = new BitmapFont();
    color = new Color(0,0,0,1);
    style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.font = font;
    style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(WizardsDuel.atlas.findRegion("GUI/guibg"));
    style.fontColor = color;

    handler = new ChangeHandler();
    ArrayList<User> users = FirebaseManager.lobbyUsers;
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size() || i < 100; i++){
        TextButton tmp = new TextButton("",style);
        tmp.scale(2);
        //tmp.setText(users.get(i).name);
        tmp.setText(i+ "   asdf");
        tmp.addListener(handler);
        table.add(tmp).width(WIDTH/4f);
        if(i%2 == 1 && i > 0)
            table.row();
    }
```

Despite the manner in which the table clearly extends below the bottom of the screen(which should be the bottom of the scroll pane), there is no scroll bar, and clicking and dragging does nothing.

Screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that is wasn't receiving input.  My I shouldn't have set the input processor in the constructor, because, the previous screen was setting the processor to null when it was "hidden", so when I moved the line to LobbyScreen's show method it happened after the previous screen was hidden, and the input is set correctly.

Answer (score 8):

You do actually need two things. An outer Container and an inner Container. You do regularly use two Tables for this. So here is a small example how I use the scrollPane. Actually with no style but it should make it clear.

```
this.table = new Table();
this.container = new Table();
scroll = new ScrollPane(table);
container.add(scroll).width(500f).height(500f);
container.row();
```

The table is the table one where you do add the stuff that should be scrollable. The container is the outer box. So you can add for example a headline above your scrollbox. The outer box (container) does need a size. Else you will not have any scrollbars or such. And you do need the inner table.

Simple example for adding:

```
style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
label = new Label(null, style);
table.add(label);
table.row();
label.setAlignment(1); // align center
```

give it more lines that it can show and you'll have a scroll pane. Else there is no scrollbar or such.

All in one. You just missed the outer container i think. Add it and it should work. Don't forget to sett the sizes.

Comment: Also, where did you get Config.VIRTUAL_VIEW_WIDTH?

Comment: ... this is a static float i use in my programm. Replace it with some value

Comment: I did, I used a static field called WIDTH.  I'm going to edit my post so it shows the container

Comment: I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: did you tried to scroll down? jsut by holding the mouse pressed .. maybe just the style does not work. the rest does look right i think

Comment: Yeah, I have, but I just realized something. The buttons aren't working like I would expect them to either.  Maybe my stage isn't distrubuting/receiving input properly...  I set the input processor... And you can download a desktop version here:  http://hobogames.atspace.cc/ (Just click the wizard wars, and download the desktop version, and see for yourself what's up(It's the pvp menu)

Comment: Container in a container is a great way to handle scrollpane. I use a table, then throw my scrollpane in a cell in the table, then throw the content in there.

Answer (score 8):

maybe you forget to make stage act in render(), add something like:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
    stage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after you init the scrollpane you should call this first

```
    mScrollPane.layout();
```

Answer (score 0):

### The element to be scrolled must be added to the stage or group before passing it to the ScrollPane

1. Create the necessary actor and add it to the stage or group

   ```
   val actor = Actor()
   [Stage/Group].addActor(actor)
   ```
2. Create a ScrollPane and place an actor in it

   ```
   val scrollPane = ScrollPane(actor)
   ```
3. Set the position and dimensions for the actor and the ScrollPane

   ```
   actor.setBounds(x,y,w,h) | scrollPane.setBounds(x,y,w,h)
   ```